# Terminating app because of errors. How can i minimize these app closes

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, runtime-error, ios10

I have an app without `try catch`. App terminates when error occurred. I want to get error logs when error happen but don't terminate the app. Is this possible to handle this errors? I searched try, guard, defer but don't know how to use? Thanks.

Comment: You have to be more specific. It is definitely possible to handle errors using Swift, but we won't walk you through it step for step.

Comment: For example when i pressed button, app crash and terminate. I can find the error because i am using app with debug mode. But when app will be on app store i cant track errors because i cant reach users phone. I wonder that is there method like when app crash occured.

Comment: You cannot catch arbitrary runtime errors in Swift with `try - catch`, it affects only methods which can `throw`. Set the exception breakpoint to get more information about the crashes and test your app in the simulator and on a real device. Use `guard let` and `if let` to unwrap optionals safely.

Comment: Thanks, i will search how to use guard let and if let.

Comment: What I will add to @vadian's comment is that you can use try and catch, but only effectively if you specifically throw your own errors. I created an error class for my app, and then I would create potential for my code to throw errors in places where there is possibility for error. I don't know if that is really a good solution in your situation though.

Comment: When i am using the app, if internet is slow, i cant get data from database and get "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: This indicates that you aren't coding defensively. If there is a change that a network operation times out and something may be nil as a result then you should check for nil and handle it gracefully. Only use ! When a crash is the only reasonable response to a situation

Comment: @Paulw11 is there any easy way to improve the code? For example in `jsonData = try (NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options[]) as! NSDictionary).mutableCopy() as! NSMutableDictionary`  if i change ! to ? and when data is nil, program will terminate or not ?

Comment: You need to expand the line and use conditional unwrapping `if let jsonData = data { if let JSONDictionary = NSJSonSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options:[]) as? [String:AnyObject] {` and so on. You need `else` clauses to handle the case where the unwrap fails. Depending on your code structure you may also be able to use `guard`. Don't use foundation types (NSMutableDictionary etc) unless you absolutely have to